# 100% width for input or select in tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want the width of Title, Test1 and Test2 to fill all the "td" (except the label) automatically, instead of set its width.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><span class='star'>*</span><label>Title:</label>{{ form.name }}</td>
        </tr>
            <td><span class='star'>*</span><label>Test1:</label>{{ form.dataSecrecy }}</td>
            <td><span class='star'>*</span><label>Test2:</label>{{ form.costType }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Example:
[image]

I want to make they like this:

[image]

not this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<input style='width:100%;' ...>`

Comment: or `<select style='width:100%;' ...`

Comment: The `<form>` tag line feeds.  You can restyle it so that it is `<form style='display:inline;'>`

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about line feeds.  What is it you're trying to achieve?  Line feeds between tags in a table don't do anything.

Comment: @Danfi - If you put the labels in their own td, then that won't happen.

Comment: I know ,but if one of the label is too long, this row will not be beautiful.

Comment: So set the td to a `max-width` and set `overflow:hidden`